# Spring Boot, the port 443 may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured

Tags: tomcat, networking, spring-boot

I have looked for solution but without success. My first step was scanning opened ports:

```
$ lsof -n -i
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    2505 adam  191u  IPv6  29475      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:9300 (LISTEN)
java    2505 adam  193u  IPv6  29483      0t0  TCP localhost:9300 (LISTEN)
java    2505 adam  242u  IPv6  32882      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:9200 (LISTEN)
java    2505 adam  243u  IPv6  28669      0t0  TCP localhost:9200 (LISTEN)
firefox 4193 adam   48u  IPv4 132995      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.104:41492->waw02s05-in-f14.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 4193 adam   78u  IPv4 136834      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.104:50010->waw02s07-in-f170.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 4193 adam   82u  IPv4 118882      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.104:60282->waw02s07-in-f174.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 4193 adam   98u  IPv4 131071      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.104:38022->151.101.193.69:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 4193 adam  115u  IPv4  47061      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.104:47570->192.0.73.2:https (ESTABLISHED)
java    4416 adam   14u  IPv4 141527      0t0  TCP localhost:39235->localhost:42200 (ESTABLISHED)
java    4416 adam   62u  IPv4 133369      0t0  TCP localhost:37871->localhost:51470 (ESTABLISHED)
java    4416 adam  171u  IPv4 125198      0t0  TCP *:39235 (LISTEN)
java    4416 adam  194u  IPv4 118604      0t0  TCP localhost:6942 (LISTEN)
java    4416 adam  435u  IPv4 119554      0t0  TCP localhost:63342 (LISTEN)
java    4416 adam  447u  IPv4 119565      0t0  TCP localhost:37871 (LISTEN)
java    4647 adam   32u  IPv6 125195      0t0  TCP *:23559 (LISTEN)
java    4647 adam   76u  IPv6 125196      0t0  TCP *:34679 (LISTEN)
java    4647 adam   77u  IPv6 138676      0t0  TCP localhost:42200->localhost:39235 (ESTABLISHED)
java    5334 adam  108u  IPv4 129812      0t0  TCP localhost:51470->localhost:37871 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Inside [this link](http://textuploader.com/dkszd) you can find error of application

**applicatiom.yml**

```
server:
  port: 443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: ontrack
    key-store: "keystore.p12"
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store-password: password
    key-password: password
  undertow:
    ioThreads: 15
    workerThreads: 150
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mimeTypes: text/xml, text/css, text/plain, text/html, application/json, application/javascript
    minResponseSize: 512
```

I want to use url without port, to open my site.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to forwarding port 443 to 8443 ?

Comment: This is more a networking question, linux based os generally do not allow binding port 0 to 1024. Try a IP table rule like `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443`

Comment: See correct answer from Jason C using authbind here:
https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443/892391#892391